# Default Values for CGFloat, CGSize, minFontSize etc. in a wrapper function

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, wrapper, sizewithfont

I have code which has a ton of `sizeWithFont` calls that I need to desperately get rid off since sizeWithFont has been deprecated. Now, I have sort of figured out how to use `boundingRectWithSize` in its stead, however, instead of re-doing a million calls, I thought of making a wrapper function to do the sizeWithFonts.

So, here's the method I came up with :

```
- (CGSize) getSizeForCurrentFont:(UIFont*)font
                    forWidth:(CGFloat)width
           constrainedToSize:(CGSize)size
               lineBreakMode:(NSLineBreakMode)lineBreakMode
                 minFontSize:(CGFloat)minFontSize
              actualFontSize:(CGFloat *)actualFontSize
{
    // functionality
}
```

What I am going for is that only the values that are set will be called while the rest will be whatever the default value for them should be. So, if a call only has font and width, only that will be set. I do understand that fontSize is no longer supported, but I'd appreciate suggestions on that.

My question is : what are the default values that I should set font,width,size,lineBreakMode,minFontSize and actualFontSize to so that I don't get weird results. Essentially, I want the same result for :

```
[s sizeWithFont:font
constrainedToSize:size];
```

as with :

```
[s getSizeForCurrentFont:font 
forWidth:width #This is some Default Value# 
constrainedToSize:size 
lineBreakMode:lineBreakMode #This is some Default Value# 
minFontSize:minFontSize #This is some Default Value# 
actualFontSize: actualFontSize #This is some Default Value#]
```

Do tell me if any further clarification is required. If you can suggest a nice way to do boundingRectWithSize, then that would be cool as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap primitives into objects? So you'd have:

```
- (CGSize) getSizeForCurrentFont:(UIFont*)font
                    forWidth:(NSNumber*)width
           constrainedToSize:(NSValue*)size
               lineBreakMode:(NSNumber*)lineBreakMode
                 minFontSize:(NSNumber*)minFontSize
              actualFontSize:(NSNumber*)actualFontSize
{
    // functionality
}
```

Any 'default' values would be set to nil. For `CGFloat`, you'd create them using:

```
CGFloat value = 10.0f;
NSNumber* valueObj = @(value);
```

For `NSValue`, you can use:

```
CGSize size = CGSizeMake(10.0f, 10.0f);
NSValue* sizeObj = [NSValue valueWithCGSize:size];
```

The key issue here, is how to differentiate between a valid value and an absence identifier. Typically you do this using either a defined constant (such as `NSNotFound`), but for the types you've listed such a thing doesn't exist. This is where objects can help, as the lack of an object inherently indicates the absence of a value.

Comment: yeah I don't think you are giving good advice on literal boxing variables here.

Comment: @GradyPlayer Can you elaborate as to why?

Comment: you are suggesting that they try @(someStruct) which certainly doesn't work... and your @(CGFloat) notation is confusing....

Comment: The idea of wrapping is not a bad one, very valid in a lot of cases... not being critical of that strategy

Comment: I misunderstood, I thought you meant the strategy was bad! No worries, edited the answer for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a method:

```
- (CGSize) sizeWithFont:(UIFont*)font constrainedToSize:(CGSize)size {
    [self getSizeForCurrentFont:font 
        forWidth:#some Default Value# 
        constrainedToSize:size 
        lineBreakMode:#some Default Value# 
        minFontSize:#some Default Value# 
        actualFontSize:#some Default Value#]
}
```

This is the simpliest way of creating "default values".

Comment: Whilst that was the example provided, I get the impression you could have various permutations of parameters, meaning creating methods such as these would be unscalable.

Comment: Hey, Thanks a lot. But I'm looking for... what should the right default value for say a lineBreakMode that has not been set should be.

Comment: Yes, that's not scalable. Yes, that is not the real "default value" for the method parameter. But there are no default parameters in Objective-C. I believe that you can use them in Objective-C++, but it is the C++ feature, not Objective-C's.

Comment: Ah, now I understand what you mean. You will have to select default values for each parameter. And because you control both methods (full and short one) you can hide this as an implementation detail. Do not see better solution right now. :)

Answer (score 0):

Update Swift 4.2

```
 let size = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
```